# Сортировка по нескольким столбцам

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Необходимо найти самый убыточный фильм с 2012 по 2014 года (включительно).

Получилось найти самый убыточный фильм в заданных годах по отдельности с помощью подобного кода: `data.loc[data.release_year==2012].sort_values(by='revenue',ascending=True)['original_title'].iloc[0]`

Как включить несколько лет в поиск?

Пример датафрейма: [image: датафрейм]

Comment: это не пример датафрейма. это фотография примера датафрейма. представьте, вам в место ответа скриншот ответа пришлют?

Comment: @strawdog а как таблицу адекватно вставить? пытался просто копирнуть, а она разъезжается

Comment: @yegor, посмотрите [любой из ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1245160/edit) с отформатированным кодом в качестве примера

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться методами: `.query()` и `.nsmallest()`:

```
res = (data
       .eval("profit = revenue - budget")
       .query("2012 <= release_year <= 2014")
       .nsmallest(1, "profit")
       ["original_title"])
```

Comment: А как сортировать не по revenue, а по revenue - budget?

Comment: @yegor Сделайте колонку с этими значениями, да и сортируйте по ней

Comment: @yegor, можно добавить столбец "на лету", используя метод `.assign(profit=revenue-budget)`

Answer (score 5):

Включить несколько лет в условие - например, с помощью `isin`:

```
data.loc[data.release_year.isin([2012,2013,2014])]
```

Сортировать по `revenue - budget` - сделайте новую колонку:

```
data['profit'] = data['revenue'] - data['budget']
```

И потом сортируйте по этой колонке.